# Impala JDBC connection: Error setting/closing session: Open Session Error

Tags: jdbc, impala, squirrel-sql

If I have the following type of impala connection, can I still use SquirreL SQL:

```
    self.impala_con = connect(host='sql.edamame.com', port=25003, use_ssl=True, auth_mechanism="PLAIN",
                              user='edamame1', password='edamamePass')
```

Here is how I set the Alias in Squirrel:

[image]

I got the following errors during test connection:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500151) Error setting/closing session: Open Session Error.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$100(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$2.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

Update:

I also tried the URL below:

```
jdbc:impala://sql.edamame.com:25003/default;AuthMech=3;SSL=1
```

and get the following new errors:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500310) Invalid operation: null;
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$100(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$2.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What else I might be missing? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: RTFM.

Long answer: the Cloudera JDBC driver ships with a 80+ pages PDF "Install and Config guide". Don't be shy, open it. You may go directly to *Appendix A - driver config* and look at these entries:

> ***AuthMech*** The authentication mechanism to use.
>   Set the value to one of the following numbers:
>  0 for No Authentication
>  1 for Kerberos
>  2 for User Name
>  3 for User Name and Password
>
> ***SSL***
>   When this property is set to 1, the driver communicates with the Impala server through an SSL-enabled socket. When this property is set to 0, the driver does not connect to SSL-enabled sockets.

So your URL should look like
`jdbc:impala://blahblah:25003/default;AuthMech=3;SSL=1`

One more thing: to troubleshoot SSL handshake issues, you may enable the debug traces with this Java system property...
`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

Comment: Thanks Samson, I tried the URL you suggested, and then got a new error (see update in the question). Do you know what I missed? Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame, I would bet on a SSL certificate validation issue -- either your server uses a self-signed certificate, or it uses a certificate signed by a Corporate C.A. that has not been listed in the default TrustStore of your JRE. Enable the debug trace flag to be sure, then if it is the case, learn about Java properties `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `.trustStorePassword`; learn also about the `keytool` utility to create a custom TrustStore in JKS format. Have fun...!

Comment: @Edamame, on second thoughts, an SSL certificate validation issue would be MUCH MORE verbose about what has happened (with `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`). Google about that error code and ImpalaJDBCDriver and have fun...!